# How can we use the helper from another app's module in Symfony1.4?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, helper

How can we use the helper from another app's module in Symfony1.4?

I want to reuse the same helper class without duplicating content.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest and recommended way would be moving this helper out of the apps, to the project lib/helper directory.

You can also use the fact that $moduleName parameter is not really validated nor escaped in sfApplicationConfiguration::getHelperDirs(), however moving it looks much cleaner than this dirty workaround:

```
sfContext::getInstance()->getConfiguration()->loadHelpers(['Test'], '../../other_app/modules/other_module');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Although i didn't tested the above solution but it looks fine. I ended up moving that helper to plugin directory which I included in the needed app.